# My Java Web client not accessing server folders which are shared

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am giving image path as `://serverIp/image/xyz.jpg` but I am not showing image on my client application.

For this what i have to do?

I am writting my code as: `FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(path);`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Windows network shares? If so, you should use [UNC paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention). Your path isn't a valid UNC path, so your file will not be found. Also, for reading files from shares, you could use an [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html).

Try the following:

```
File filetoRead = new File(new URI("\\\\serverIp\\image\\xyz.jpg"));
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileToRead);
```

Note that all backslashes are used twice, this is done to escape the backslashes.

Comment: your solution is working for server but on client still i am not getting an image when i access same application from client

Comment: Is your share available at your client when you navigate to it using Windows Explorer? Also, do you get an exception?

Comment: i am able to access server folders from client from windows explorer..how can i know the exception that is on client side?

Comment: Check your console and/or logging, put a breakpoint and see what happens.

Comment: Also, I added another suggestion which might help.